# "Ch++" or "ch+1" in C++?

Tags: c++, cout

While reading "C++ Primer Plus 5th edition", I saw this piece of code:

```
    cin.get(ch);
    ++ch;
    cout << ch;
```

So, this will lead to display the following character after ch. But, If I did it that way:

```
    cin.get(ch);
    cout << ch+1;
```

Now, cout will think ch is an int(try typecasting). So, why cout does so?
And why if I added 1 to a char it will produce a number?. And why there's a difference between:
ch++, and ch + 1.

Comment: you probably want ch = ch + 1

Comment: I think he means cout << ch + 1, which indeed prints an int instead of a char

Comment: Thanks itsadok, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason this occurs is the type of the literal `1` is int. When you add an int and a char you get an int, but when you increment a char, it remains a char.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_type(char)
{
    std::cout << "char\n";
}
void print_type(int)
{
    std::cout << "int\n";
}
void print_type(long)
{
    std::cout << "long\n";
}

int main()
{
    char c = 1;
    int i = 1;
    long l = 1;

    print_type(c); // prints "char"
    print_type(i); // prints "int"
    print_type(l); // prints "long"

    print_type(c+i); // prints "int"
    print_type(l+i); // prints "long"
    print_type(c+l); // prints "long"

    print_type(c++); // prints "char"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: print_type(c+c); // prints "int"

Comment: @Avram: yep, binary arithmetic operators never operate on less than an int. It's fairly early on in the spec.

Answer (score 8):

**Please note - this is the answe to the original question, which has since been edited.**

> Now, cout will think ch is an int(try
>   typecasting).

No it won't. It is not possible to change the type of a variable in C++.

```
++ch;
```

increments whatever is in ch.

ch + 1;

takes the value (contents) of ch, adds 1 to it and discards the result. Whatever is in ch is unchanged.

Comment: What on earth gave me this idea?:D

Comment: -1 because you don't answer the question which was "why does c+1 gives an int?" which has a real answer. See answer from @itsadok

Comment: @Vincent The questioner has changed the question since I answered it - see the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `++ch;` increments `ch` whereas `ch + 1;` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Also, rememeber that '++ch' will do the increment before actually running the statement it is in, so that is why it remains a char.

```
int i = 0;
cout << ++i << endl;
cout << i++ << endl;
// both will print out 1.
```